# How to procced in following integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, intuition

We have to find the following integration .

I tried it a lot , but stuck how to proceed . [image]

Please help

Comment: This is your  18th post. So your next step should be to replace the picture by Latex formulas.

Comment: @miracle173 but I am comfortable with this ,please . And I am not good at latex.

Comment: Her is a tutorial: [Math Jax Tutorial and Quick Reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @miracle173 why i cannot post like this

Comment: It's often difficult to read, impossible to copy directly, non-standard, and not a viable solution if you would ever choose to publish or submit a formal paper. It's easy to learn, and immensely useful.

Comment: @JacobAustin okay i would take care of it . Can you help me in this problem or in the given answer bylab bhattacharjee

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Divide the numerator & the denominator by $x^{10}$ of
$$F=\dfrac{5x^4+4x^5}{(x^5+x+1)^2}$$
to find
$$F=\dfrac{5x^{-6}+4x^{-5}}{(1+x^{-4}+x^{-5})^2}$$

$\dfrac{d(1+x^{-4}+x^{-5})}{dx}=?$

OR

Replace $x$ with $\dfrac1y$

Comment: Thriugh this I am getting the result , but that is not matching with the answer but both result are correct as on differentiating they are giving the same result. Why is this so ?

Comment: The answer is ( $-x-1$)$/$$($$x^5$$+$$x+1$$)$

Comment: This is an interesting problem. The answer you get using the method above is $1/(x^{-5}+x^{-4}+1) + c$, but koolman's answer is the standard answer Mathematica gives. They are both correct, but differ by a constant $c=-1$.

$$\frac{1}{x^{-5}+x^{-4}+1} -1 = \frac{−x−1}{x^5+x+1}$$

Comment: @JacobAustin so both are correct answer

Comment: Yes. Integration is only unique up to an additive constant. The integral of $f'(x)$ is $f(x)+C$ where $C$ is an unspecified constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can Directly Solved it::

Let $$I = \int\frac{4x^5+5x^4}{(x^5+x+1)^2}dx$$

Put $\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{t}\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dx = -\frac{1}{t^2}dt$

So $$I = -\int\frac{(4+5t)\cdot t^5}{(t^5+t^4+1)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{t^2}dt = -\int\frac{4t^3+5t^4}{(t^5+t^4+1)^2}dt$$

So we get $\displaystyle (t^5+t^4+1)=u\;,$ Then $(5t^4+4t^3)dt = du$

So $$I = -\int\frac{1}{u^2}du = \frac{1}{u}+\mathcal{C} = \frac{1}{t^5+t^4+1}+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I = \int\frac{4x^5+5x^4}{(x^5+x+1)^2}dx = \frac{x^5}{x^5+x+1}+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: Find OR part in my answer.

Comment: Yes   lab bhattacharjee  I did not see that part.